# Pass serialized form with other data parameters

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I have a jQuery ajax function and would like to submit an entire form as post data and will transfer some data parameter as well.

```
var serial = $("#formProjectBilling").serialize();

$.ajax({
    url: base_url+"sales/Sales_invoice_form/saveSalesInvoice",
    type: 'post',
    data: serial + { 
        'orderItems': orderItems, 
        'orderTotal': totalamt, 
        'freight': freight,
        'gen_disc':gen_disc,
        'otp': otp,
        'notes': $("#notes").val(),
        'idno': $("#idno").val(),
        'acctno': $("#hdnAcctNo").val(),
        'itemlocid': $("#location_id").val(),
        'shipping_id': $("#shipping_id").val(),
        'sales_date': $("#sales_date").val(),
        'discamt': $("#discount").text(),
        'gendisctype': $("#gen_disc_type").val()
    },
```

It only transfers the serialized form, but not the other data in parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to convert your object to url param query:

```
var str = "";
for (var key in yourData) {
    if (str != "") {
        str += "&";
    }
    str += key + "=" + yourData[key];
}
```

then into your ajax in the line where you pass data, just use the converted url:

```
...
data: serial + '&' + str;
...
```

Full Code:

```
var serial = $("#formProjectBilling").serialize();
// your data
var data = {
  'orderItems': orderItems,
  'orderTotal': totalamt,
  'freight': freight,
  'gen_disc': gen_disc,
  'otp': otp,
  'notes': $("#notes").val(),
  'idno': $("#idno").val(),
  'acctno': $("#hdnAcctNo").val(),
  'itemlocid': $("#location_id").val(),
  'shipping_id': $("#shipping_id").val(),
  'sales_date': $("#sales_date").val(),
  'discamt': $("#discount").text(),
  'gendisctype': $("#gen_disc_type").val()
}
// conversion object to url params
var str = "";
for (var key in data) {
  if (str != "") {
    str += "&";
  }
  str += key + "=" + data[key];
}

$.ajax({
  url: base_url + "sales/Sales_invoice_form/saveSalesInvoice",
  type: 'post',
  data: serial + '&' + str
})
```

Comment: How to get the data in controller mate?

Comment: I understand the logic mate but how can I fetch the data in the controller? I'm using  $totalamt    = sanitize($this->input->post('orderTotal')); earlier.

Comment: I tried your code but OrderTotal shows nothing. print_r($total_amt);
        die();

Comment: Enjoy this [tutorial](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/jquery-ajax-request-example-in-codeigniterexample.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 var serial = $("#formProjectBilling").serializeArray();

                $.ajax({
                    url: base_url+"sales/Sales_invoice_form/saveSalesInvoice",
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {...serial,...{ 
                        'orderItems': orderItems, 
                        'orderTotal': totalamt, 
                        'freight': freight,
                        'gen_disc':gen_disc,
                        'otp': otp,
                        'notes': $("#notes").val(),
                        'idno': $("#idno").val(),
                        'acctno': $("#hdnAcctNo").val(),
                        'itemlocid': $("#location_id").val(),
                        'shipping_id': $("#shipping_id").val(),
                        'sales_date': $("#sales_date").val(),
                        'discamt': $("#discount").text(),
                        'gendisctype': $("#gen_disc_type").val()
                    },
```

Comment: The serial didnt transfer mate

Comment: serialize will give name=value&name=value like that. we can't concat with object.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery `serialize()` function effectively turns the form values into a valid query string. Use `$.param(object)` to send other params in some object variable

```
var values = [
  { 'orderItems': orderItems },
  { 'orderTotal': orderTotal },
  { 'freight': freight }
  { ... }
]

var data = form.serialize() + '&' + $.param(values);
```

Read more http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/